# focus for ng-select not working Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, focus

i'm trying to use focus for ng-select in angular 5 but its not working

i'm working with [ng2-select](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)

---

How to use focus for ng-select in Angular 5 ?

```
<label class="input">
   <input (blur)="goTo()" type="text">
</label>

<label class="select" >
    <div *ngIf="items.length > 0" >
       <ng-select     #select [items]="items">
       </ng-select>
    </div>
</label>





@ViewChild('select') myElement: ElementRef;

    goTo(){
      this.myElement.element.nativeElement.focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
goTo(){
  this.myElement.element.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

to this,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor (private cRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

// import 'SelectComponent' from your library for 'ng2-select'
goTo(){
  let el = null;
  if (this.items.length > 0) {
    this.cRef.detectChanges();
    el = (this.myElement.nativeElement as SelectComponent).element.nativeElement.querySelector('div.ui-select-container > input');
    if (el) { el.focus(); }
  }
}
```

You may have to check if the element is defined or not (or if you need an extra 'nativeElement' in there, but I'm basically reusing the logic in [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/blob/855ac2fa02793b05afef2b1156cace96f418fc84/src/select/select.ts#L550).

Just a cautionary note, this may not be a stable fix though if the library updates to rename these classes or modify the template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when I use this expression:
goTo(){
  this.myElement.nativeElement.focus();
}
he tells me that nativeElement is undefined

Comment: I updated my answer. May be the element is not yet present in the dom initially when the `items.length` is not greater than `0`

Comment: (this.myElement.nativeElement as SelectComponent)   is undefined

Comment: <label class="input">
   <input  type="text" tabindex="1">
</label>

<label class="select" >
    <div *ngIf="items.length > 0" >
       <ng-select     tabindex="2"  [items]="items">
       </ng-select>
    </div>
</label>

Comment: this.myElement.nativeElement as SelectComponent) is undefined  again

Comment: the nativeElement is undifined if i try " this.myElement.nativeElement" but it work only when we use the expression "this.myElement.element.nativeElement" .

Comment: It’s usually good to debug it properly and call it the right way. If it works for you, then great!

Answer (score 5):

this works fine for me,

```
@ViewChild('ngSelect') ngSelect: NgSelectComponent;
ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.autofocus) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.ngSelect.focus();
            });
        }
    }
```

refer https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/762

Answer (score 1):

A Simple way, you can do this also.

```
<label class="input">
   <input (blur)="goTo(select)" type="text">
</label>

<label class="select">
    <div *ngIf="items.length > 0">
       <ng-select #select [items]="items">
       </ng-select>
    </div>
</label>
```

And in Typescript File.

```
goTo(select){
   select.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick reply, in this solution,each select elements are recorded for future usage (and in this case , blur). This needs being adapted to your situation.

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})


export class EditorComponent implements AfterViewInit {

// Viewchildren
// https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e
myindex:number;

@ViewChildren("select") inputs: QueryList<any>

constructor() { 
  this.myindex=0
}

// You will have to setup some input parameters in this function in order to switch to the right "select", (you have control)
private goTo() 
{
// focus next input field
if (this.myindex +1 < this.inputs.toArray().length)
  {
  this.inputs.toArray()[this.myindex +1].nativeElement.focus();
  this.myindex = this.myindex + 1;
  }
else {
  this.inputs.toArray()[0].nativeElement.focus();
  this.myindex = 0;
}
}

private processChildren(): void {
  console.log('Processing children. Their count:', this.inputs.toArray().length)
}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("AfterViewInit");
    console.log(this.inputs);
    this.inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input));

    // susbcribe to inputs changes, each time an element is added (very optional feature ...)
    this.inputs.changes.subscribe(_ => 
      this.processChildren() // subsequent calls to processChildren
  );
}


  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add '#id' to ngSelect element

```
<ng-select #id></ng-select>
```

then add:
`@ViewChild('id') Ele: NgSelectComponent;`
in the component.ts file
then focus using: `this.Ele.focus()`, it will focus